# How to reformat Kali Linux to different version of Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kali-linux

I have an old iMac that I reformatted to run Kali Linux a few years back. It boots straight into Kali Linux, and is not a dual boot. The Mac OS was completely wiped. Now, I want to put a new version of Ubuntu on that machine, but I can't figure out how to boot to a USB installer in Kali Linux.

Normally when I plug in a USB installer - I can press a key on startup and boot to that disk. I'm not seeing the USB drive as an option in the startup menu for Kali Linux. I do see the options to boot into safe mode.

Is there a key combination I can press on startup to access alternative boot drives? I was hoping to access this through a GUI of some sort. If not, I'm comfortable accessing the drive through the command-line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else stumbles across this, I found the fix.

Since I had wiped Mac completely from the hard drive, the startup commands stopped working. That included Disk Recovery, Boot Drive Selection, Safe Mode, etc. I can't confirm that is the case with all macs, but I had two with the same issue.

Plug in your bootable drive and start your machine.

When the computer starts up, you'll see the linux menu flash for about 3 seconds. During this time press 'c'. This will open the Grub command line.

Now, you'll need to figure out what (hd*) your bootable drive is mounted at. Run `ls` to list all of them. On both of my macs the bootable drive was mounted at `(hd0)`.

To find your USB drive, run the following commands to list the files in each volume.

```
set root=(hd0)
find /         ----- (Press Tab after '/' to show results)

Returns:  
.. /boot /isolinux .. etc
```

Once you've identified your bootable drive, there are two ways to get the machine to boot from the USB device.

Set Root, Exit (Worked for me)

Basically, you'll just set the new boot root to your boot drive, then exit.

```
set root=(hd0)
exit
```

This worked for me, after trying to custom configure the boot with flags. See below.

Pass Boot Configs to Drive

Read a lot of people having success when their USB's aren't booting. I started here, which eventually led me to my solution.

```
set root=(hd0)
linux (hd0)/isolinux/vmlinuz root="/dev/sda2"
initrd (hd0)/initrd/initrd.img
boot
```

That will use your specific linux/initrd paths at boot, and try to mount the root fs at `/dev/sda2`.

**Note** - I wrote this a couple days later. Commands will need to be updated for your bootable drive. You can potentially lose files during this process.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Ignore Kali. It will not be used.

First, copy (backup).

Then tell the computer to boot from USB. This is in the boot loader. It have nothing to do with the installed OS. And nothing to do with the 2nd stage boot loader, that is loaded from disk. There will be a way to turn on your mac, to allow you to select where to boot from.

## This may work, I found it on the web.

- Power off
- Insert bootable USB
- Power on, then press and hold the Option (⌥) key immediately upon hearing the startup chime.